# Poisson solver diverged

Tags: simulation, software

My 2D-Poisson solver is build for simulation of semiconductor.

The algorithm is Gauss-Seidel iterative method.

If I use simple PN junction for simulation testing, it diverged while I applied high voltage on electrode.

But it is fine while there is no applied voltage or very low voltage applied on electrodes.

The following are example for 1D discretized equation.

[image: 1D discretized Poisson]

The right hand side have linear and exponential parts.

A small change of potential cause large difference of charge density, and the large difference of charge density cause larger change of potential in next iteration.

Is this the Possible reason that cause Poisson solver diverged?
How to avoid it?

(If the description is still unclear I can upload a part of my code.)

The following is the DD model tutorial I followed which is written by Dragica Vasileska.
https://nanohub.org/resources/1545/download/ddmodel_introductory_part_word.pdf

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I will post this question there also, thank you.

Comment: I did something kinda like this but simpler. I had numerical instabilities, but I just played around with the iteration step until I found one that worked. See http://pythonhosted.org/eq_band_diagram/ : "A little twist, which suppresses a numerical oscillation, is that net_charge[i] is inferred not from the Evac[i] at the last time step, but instead from the (Evac[i+1] + Evac[i-1])/2 at the last time step." I still don't really understand why that fixed my problem ... I found it by accident. :-P Hopefully someone will answer your question with a proper numerical stability analysis.

Comment: I'm guessing that the convergence history of your linear and nonlinear solvers will be of more use than the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that I had a big misunderstanding about the problem I am facing.

Gauss-Seidel and Jaccobi method is for linear system. And the Poisson equation I just used in my Poisson solver is called "nonlinear Poisson" due to the exponential parts at RHS.

So the numerical instability do cause by the exponential parts due to the wrong method I used to solve the nonlinear Poisson.

Now I use Newton method in my Poisson solver and it works well, thank you everyone :)